# How do I move U2 Database into SQL Server 2012 using U2 Toolkit for .NET, SSIS and Import/Export Wizard?

Tags: u2netdk

Can I use U2 Toolkit for .NET (32-bit/64-bit) to load and transfer U2 Database into SQL Server 2012? I would like to use Import/Export Wizard and Visual Studio 2010 SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio (SSIS).

Answer (score 1):

## You can do it two ways:

1. 32-bit/64-bit Import/Export SQL Server 2012 Wizard
2. 32-bit/64-bit SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) using VS2010 BIDS

**Using Import/Export Wizard**

See below screen shots

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Using SSIS ( SQL Server 2012 Business Intelligence Development Studio and VS2010)**

See screen shots below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

U2 Toolkit for .NET v1.2.1 + allows you to put U2 Database (UniVerse and UniData) as TARGET in SSIS Designer  or Import/Export Wizard.

Basically you can move data from SQL Server ( or any data source) into U2 Database.

Prior to this Release (v1.2.1) , there was an issue with INSERT statement in U2 Toolkit for .NET. Now it is resolved.